# Select order before group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

This has frustrated me a bit, and I have googled around for a while.

```
id                   int(11)                
target_id            int(11)    
text                 text   latin1_swedish_ci
ip_address           varchar(20)    latin1_swedish_ci
created_by_user_id   int(11)    
created_date         datetime
```

Data example:

```
id target_id    ip_address    created_by_user_id    text    created_date
1  113          192.168.0.1   1                     test1   2014-08-24 12:32:01
1  113          192.168.0.1   1                     test2   2014-08-24 13:32:01 
1  1            192.168.0.1   113                   test3   2014-08-21 13:32:01  
1  1            192.168.0.1   113                   test4   2014-08-22 13:32:01
```

How could I select the latest result, and also group by target_id? I have tried the following SQL statement to group correctly, but it didn't bring the latest result.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `fq_message`
GROUP BY
    target_id
ORDER BY
    id DESC
```

returns:

```
1  113          192.168.0.1   1                     test1   2014-08-24 12:32:01
1  1            192.168.0.1   113                   test3   2014-08-21 13:32:01
```

I want to achieve

```
1  113          192.168.0.1   1                     test2   2014-08-24 13:32:01 
1  1            192.168.0.1   113                   test4   2014-08-22 13:32:01
```

Comment: What if you use `SELECT id, target_id, ...., MAX(created_date) FROM ...` ? Typically, with a `GROUP BY`, all the column that aren't grouped should be handled by an **aggregation** function like `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX` or something like that ...

Comment: I am *assuming* this is MySQL since I'm seeing back-ticks as quotes, but please tag your post with the database system you're working on.

Comment: @marc_s max(created_date) will return the max created_date but not with other columns like text, target_id and ect..

Comment: @MatthewHaugen sorry i forgot to tag, it's MYSQL

Comment: just FYI, this IS the most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag. It's correctly answered quite often too.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks i have viewed few of them, didn't answer my question directly or maybe i just miss out the key info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL allows you to write queries that are formally not SQL. For example, the following query might work in MySQL, or it might not.  A sane database would certainly reject it:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        from    fq_message
        order by
                created_date desc
        ) SubQueryAlias
 group by
        target_id
```

This tells MySQL to sort before group, as you ask.  But it's not real SQL.  The SQL standard says subquery sets, and tables, are unordered.  All other databases will reject the inner query as imposing a sort order that does not matter.

The query also selects `*` but groups on `target_id`.  MySQL will grab the first value it encounters, which if it honors the subquery sort, is the latest value per target.  But there is no guarantee that it will do so.  How MySQL handles these things can even change per MySQL version.

A better approach is to write SQL that requires MySQL to do the right thing.  One such way is a filtering join with the set of latest dates per target:

```
select  msg.*
from    fq_message msg
join    (
        select  target_id
        ,       max(created_date) as max_date_for_this_target
        from    fq_message
        group  by
                target_id
        ) filter
on      msg.target_id = filter.target_id
        and msg.created_date = filter.max_date_for_this_target
```

The `join` is an `inner join` and will only return rows for which the `on` clause finds a match.  The effect is that messages that do not have the latest date for their target are filtered out.

See the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag for more approaches and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, didn't though simple task could potential ends up quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

**Try his code:**

```
SELECT
    ID, 
    target_id, 
    ID_ADDRESS, 
    CREATED_BY_USER_ID, 
    (SELECT TEXT FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] WHERE ID = TMP.ID AND TARGET_ID = TMP.TARGET_ID AND ID_ADDRESS = TMP.ID_ADDRESS AND CREATED_BY_USER_ID = TMP.CREATED_BY_USER_ID AND CREATED_DATE = TMP.CREATED_DATE), 
    CREATED_DATE

FROM
(
    SELECT 

        ID, 
        target_id, 
        ID_ADDRESS, 
        CREATED_BY_USER_ID,
        MAX(CREATED_DATE) AS CREATED_DATE 

    FROM 
    /* Instead of this from, use from [your table] */
    (
        SELECT 1 ID, 113 TARGET_ID, '192.168.0.1' ID_ADDRESS, 1   CREATED_BY_USER_ID, 'test1' TEXT, TO_DATE('2014-08-24 12:32:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') CREATED_DATE FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 1   , 113          , '192.168.0.1'           , 1                     , 'test2'     , TO_DATE('2014-08-24 13:32:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')              FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 1   , 1            , '192.168.0.1'           , 113                   , 'test3'     , TO_DATE('2014-08-21 13:32:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')              FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 1   , 1            , '192.168.0.1'           , 113                   , 'test4'     , TO_DATE('2014-08-22 13:32:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')              FROM DUAL
    )
    GROUP BY ID, target_id, ID_ADDRESS, CREATED_BY_USER_ID
) TMP
ORDER BY ID, CREATED_DATE DESC
```

**Result:**

```
1   113 192.168.0.1 1   8/24/2014 1:32:01 PM
1   1   192.168.0.1 113 8/22/2014 1:32:01 PM
```

Tested in Oracle

Comment: I don't think `select (select ... from fromAlias) from (...) fromAlias` works in MySQL, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34fd/10)

Comment: mmm, you are right. I will try to find something compatible with mySQL

Comment: When I started to write my answer, the tags were only SQL :) I'm not expert in MySQL, if I didn't find suitable answer for mySQL, I will leave my answer as it is

Comment: Please do not mark the answer as -1, partly my fault as not declare MYSQL, i will up vote to encounter the -1

Comment: @bluebill1049, I didn't down-voted nor up-voted neither your question nor the answer to your question

Comment: @simsim no someone vote you answer down, i have note up to counter it, Thanks for you answer anyhow

Comment: I don't mind being down-voted, but I prefer a down-vote with feedback via comments